# Php Mailer Has So Many Emails That My Server Times Out

Tags: loops, email, server, timeout, phpmailer

I am using PhpMailer in a while loop.  Basically I am sending about 80 emails and each email is different.  So I use the while loop to send each email individually.  The problem is this is taking so long that my server times out.  I am talking to my server guy now to increase the time limit but I doubt he is going to do it.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, avoid sending email during HTTP request processing. As you've found, it will eventually time out. There are some measures you can take to reduce this, but you won't make it go away altogether:

- Extend your timeout
- Send faster, e.g. by relaying through a local mail server

The right way to fix this is to only *trigger* the sending of your messages during the HTTP request, and do the actual sending via a cron job or other scheduled or queued task that does the actual sending. This way your trigger will do something small and simple like updating a "time to send" timestamp in a mailing list record, then have your scheduled task check for things that are are due to send, send them, and then mark them as sent so that later HTTP requests can see the status of the send.

There is [an example of sending to a mailing list](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) included with PHPMailer, and that would be exactly the kind of thing you want to trigger. Note that that code does not make any reference to `$_GET`, `$_POST`, or any other user input, it's driven purely from what's in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately i use some $_get data.  I did have an idea of making a button that can be clicked that will run the phpmailer loop by only sending one email then refreshing the page. It will $_get the last record number(email sent) and keep refreshing the page until there is no more emails left to send.  Could there be problems with this idea?

Comment: The trick there is to take the $_GET data and stick in your database somewhere, then use it in the send job. The key is in separating it into these two processes, as it makes the whole refresh/timeout problem go away.

Comment: Thanks really appreciate your time to answer.   I will give it a try.